# Positioning in CSS,I need the drop down options central but indented left

Tags: html, css, alignment, dropdown, positioning

Below HTML requires suitable CSS for the drop down links to be central but indented.
view fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/peteraejnrdev/865h2tvu/2/#&togetherjs=d3VifH4hc3

```
<div class="header-dropdown-menu">
      <ul class="top-nav">
          <li class="top-menu-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
              <li><a href="#">wood Type</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Specification</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: I've made many attempts and conducted research but still come to the same conclusion. I hate to admit defeat but pride aside, i need help and hopefully this post will help others also. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using the position property -

Set the parent to position relative (this creates the container for the child elements) 
the set the child element position to absolute. 
You can now dictate using the top/left/bottom/right properties where you want to place the element - Keep in mind that the center point of the elements will by default be placed in the top left - this means you will need to transform the elements by -50% (top and left) to center them - Example below:

```
li.top-menu-nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Please keep in mind if you would like to center the LI's you would need to add -

```
ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

also, note that the height that the child (li in this case) can be moved to will depend on the height of the parent element, giving your `top-menu-nav` a `height:100vh` will allow the menu to be placed in the center of the page.

Hope this helps, 
Wally

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation is correct, you can do something like this:

```css
.header-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-nav {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 8rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sub-nav {
  padding-left: 5rem;
}

.top-menu-nav:hover .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-dropdown-menu">
  <ul class="top-nav">
    <li class="top-menu-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="#">wood Type</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Specification</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```